# Does HTTPURLConnection go through SSH tunnel?

Tags: java, ssh, httpurlconnection

I have a program which needs to access google api, but due to I'm in china, so I have to use ssh/vpn. I opened ssh using yingwa client, and I can access the api in browser. but when I run my java code, it throw an exception:network is unreachable. 
  Anyone can help me?

ps: I didn't set a proxy for httpurlconnection

Comment: If the browser works via a proxy over that tunnel, then the HttpURLConnection needs to go through the same proxy. If not, then it should work if it accesses the same host and port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the SOCKS proxy in java to your ssh-tunnel and port.

see the chapter 2.4 here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

> There are 2 system properties related to SOCKS:
>
> `socksProxyHost` for the host name of the SOCKS proxy server
>
> `socksProxyPort` for the port number, the default value being 1080

Comment: thanks for your tips. I got the yingwa client's local port which is 65509 , and it works when I set the proxy like this: Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 65509));